# How to provide images for checkbox in an unthemed DevExpress GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I turned DevExpress Themes off for DevExpress GridView, does anybody know how to provide images for checked unchecked?

```
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView( settings => {
    settings.EnableTheming = false;
    settings.Columns.Add("isGrant", "Grant", MVCxGridViewColumnType.CheckBox);
}
```

When theming is on, I get nice check boxes in the grid, when it is off, there is no indication of any check marks, when "isGrant" is true.  Does anybody know how to show an image when true, and a different image when false when themes are off?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem ... what I did was modify the VIEW and included this property:

```
public string GrantCheck {
    get {
        return isGrant ? "<img src='/Theme/css/images/checkmark.png'>" : " ";
    }
}
```

Then in the gridview added a column with:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column => {
    column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.TextBox;
    column.FieldName = "GrantCheck";
    column.Caption = "Grant";
    column.PropertiesEdit.EncodeHtml = false;
    column.CellStyle.CssClass = "dxcheckbox";
});
```

This way I get a nice check box.  The css class is defined as:

```
.dxcheckbox { text-align: center;}
```

Cheers.